# Как эффективнее всего распарсить огромный файл логов на слабой машине?

Tags: алгоритм, файлы, логирование, highload, big-data

Есть сервер с 1gb RAM. Есть лог файл nginx (любой другой веб-сервер) на 70gb. Как максимально быстро собрать статистику по user agent пользователей сайта, учитывая описанные ограничения по ресурсам.

Comment: я сталкивался с такой проблемой. мне помог StringTokenizer. попробуйте использовать это для чтения строк

Comment: вопрос не относится ни к нагруженным системам, ни к бигдате

Comment: @etki: ... ни к алгоритмам, ни к веб-программированию.

Comment: С чего это он не относится  указынным тема? Веб-программирвоание -да согласен тут мимо. Биг дата помоему впполне подходит, так ка кработа с огромными данными. Если 70гб смущает давайте на 700 заменим. Алгоритмы тоже считаю как часть оптимизации. Нагруженные системы - тут спорно но раз у нас есть сервак чьих возможностей не хватает для полноценной обработки данных, то можно считать что имеем дело с высокой нагрузкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно воспользоваться StringTokenizer в языке Java, который позволяет считывать файл построчно и не тратить память на хранение всех строк файла.

```
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer("/path/to/file");
while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String line = tok.nextToken();
    // работаешь со строкой.
}
```

Также можно указывать разделитель в конструкторе, по умолчанию стоит `\t\n\r\f`

Comment: У `StringTokenizer` вроде нету конструктора, принимающего путь к файлу?

Comment: А как у этого решения со временем? Успеем ли мы аз приемлимое распарсить большой фалй?

Comment: @Artur более 90% времени уйдет на парсинг файла, а не чтение. так что чтение идет очень быстро. это я убедился на собственном опыте

Answer (score 5):

Считываете файл построчно и анализируете считанную сроку. Практически во всех языках можно указать размер буфера при работе с файловой системой и поэтому, несмотря на то, что вы работаете с файлом построчно, система будет читать файл фиксированными блоками.

Comment: А я бы мапнул файл в память и сделал madvize с MADV_SEQUENTIAL

Comment: @avp можно поподробнее о вашем варианте? также можете офомить ка кответ его

Comment: [man mmap -- map  files or devices into memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (только учтите, у вас этот способ имеет смысл, только если система 64-разрядная)